# Strange vertical bars between characters on Xwindows

Tags: fonts, x-windows

Some coworkers of mine are having trouble using an Xwindows application hosted on a RHEL9 box, where lots of small vertical bars appear on the screen seemingly randomly.

Sometimes in a text entry area:

[image]

And sometimes overlaid on parts of the GUI:

[image]

The only commonality is that they both have new Macs, with the latest version of XQuartz (2.8.5).

I don't have this issue, neither on a quite old Mac with XQuartz 2.7.11, nor on a Windows 10 box with XMing 6.9.0.31.

The issue also does not happen for any of us on an older RHEL6 host running the same application.

Is this a font issue?

And the really weird part is that when they are screensharing on Zoom, the audience does not see the vertical bars; they are only on the person's local screen.  They had to send me these screenshots so that I could even see the problem.